# want to implement sound or media player when clicked on recycler view

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview

In media player this keyword is showing error, because we cannot use context in recycler view , how to play sound when clicked on recycler view . is there any way to do it simply.

---

```
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    private TextView p_name,p_quant,p_cat,p_earn;
    private ImageView p_img,plus;
    public ViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);

        p_name = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.list_product);
        p_quant = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.list_quantity);
        p_cat = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.list_category);
        p_earn = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.earning);
        p_img = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.list_productimg);
        plus = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.plusoffers);

        plus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                plus.setImageResource(R.drawable.check_small);
                final MediaPlayer mp;
                mp = MediaPlayer.create(this ,R.raw.applause);
                mp.start();

            }
        });
    }
}
```

---

**My logCat**

```
Error:(91, 58) error: no suitable method found for create(<anonymous   OnClickListener>,int)
method MediaPlayer.create(Context,Uri) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; <anonymous OnClickListener> cannot be converted to  Context)
method MediaPlayer.create(Context,int) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; <anonymous OnClickListener> cannot be converted to Context)
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some messages have been simplified; recompile with -Xdiags:verbose to  get full output
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

Comment: Use mp = MediaPlayer.create(v.getContext() ,R.raw.applause); . Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks @Jickson , it works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same problem as I am trying to implement onClickListener for views created on the custom adapter.

As mentioned, the workaround for this error would be to get the context of the view

```
plus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(v.getContext(), R.raw.applause);
                mp.start();
            }
        });
```